# An extra dot in output while using foreach in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to read a file that consists of filenames and write the db query - mv class.module.example.php class.module.examplejason.php for each filename into a file.

This is my code:

```
$lines = file('/home/Staging/txts/textFile.txt');
$developer = "jason";
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{
    $fileNameArray = array_reverse(explode("/",$line));
    $fileNameArray2 = array_reverse(explode(".",$fileNameArray[0]));
    $fileNameArray2[1] = $fileNameArray2[1].$developer;
    $fileNameArray3 = array_reverse($fileNameArray2);
    $j=0;

    for($i=1;$i<count($fileNameArray2);$i++)
    {
            $dot=".";
            if($j==$i)
            { 
              $dot="";
            }
            $devFileName = $devFileName.$fileNameArray3[$i].$dot;
             $j++;
    }
    $fileNameArray4 = $fileNameArray;
    $fileNameArray4[0] = $devFileName;

    $fileNameArray4 = implode("/",array_reverse($fileNameArray4));

    echo "mv ".$fileNameArray[0]." ".$fileNameArray4."\r\n";
}
```

Issues:

1. The output I get at the end of the for loop is: `class.module.examplejason.php .`
   Why do I get the last `.`? What am I doing wrong?

   If my file has 2 filenames, like /home/Staging/class.module.example.php and /home/Staging/class.module.anotherExample.php, the output is:

   `mv class.module.example.php /home/Staging/class.module.examplejason.php .
   mv class.module.anotherExample.php /home/Staging/class.module.anotherExamplejason.php .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is incorrect.  You can use `implode` for the same purpose:

```
<?php
$lines = file('/home/Staging/txts/textFile.txt');
$developer = "jason";
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{
    $fileNameArray = array_reverse(explode("/",$line));
    $fileNameArray2 = array_reverse(explode(".",$fileNameArray[0]));
    $fileNameArray2[1] = $fileNameArray2[1].$developer;
    $fileNameArray3 = array_reverse($fileNameArray2);

    $fileNameArray4 = $fileNameArray;
    $fileNameArray4[0] = implode(".",$fileNameArray3);

    $fileNameArray4 = implode("/",array_reverse($fileNameArray4));

    echo "mv ".$fileNameArray[0]." ".$fileNameArray4."\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$j=0;
```

to

```
$j=count($fileNameArray2);
```

Comment: I don't think that would work.. I would have to change the entire loop then.

Comment: @mercy The loop is wrong anyway.  This would be a step in the right direction.  You'd also need to remove `$j++` and initialize `$i` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are `echo`ing `$fileNameArray4`, which you set above using `$fileNameArray4 = $fileNameArray;`. `$fileNameArray` is an array (generated by `array_reverse(explode("/",$line))`), so you are getting a dot from that. Don't try to echo an array.

Comment: The array isn't be echoed.  It'd imploded first, which turns it into a string.  It's misleading because of the variable name.

Comment: I tried `print_r($fileNameArray4)` now. And I got `/home/Staging/class.module.anotherExamplejason.php .` That's a string right?